# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Possible driver issue?

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, formatting, numberformatexception

I am trying to run a Java application that two other colleagues can run without issue. The application reads an excel file, places it in tables in Access and compares. I was **originally** getting

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Undefined function 'replace' in expression.
```

but I [fixed that issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45242437/2144390) by upgrading Microsoft Access Driver version 12.x to version 14.x.

My question is, **is it possible to get the following error because of a similar issue?** Meaning since we know the code is OK, do I need an upgraded version of something?

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points
```

Here is an example of a place that throws the error

```
variterrhourlyrate = (Double.valueOf(sbHourlyRate.toString())).doubleValue();
```

Comment: It sounds like a data issue.

Comment: It sounds to me like a localization issue. What is `sbHourlyRate.getClass().getName()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)